# Outlook 2013: Can I increase the number of recent "move to folder" folders list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

Well, as described in the subject, I'd like to have more recent folders in the "move to folder" menu. Can it be achieved?
Thanks.

Comment: Unbelievable that this limit still exists in Outlook 365 in 2023....

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I increase the number of recent "move to folder" in the folders list?

No it is not possible.

There are some alternatives:

> The "Move to folder" MRU list is limited to 10 lists, and it can't be
>   expanded. We can either use Quick Steps or macros to move emails to
>   predefined folders.
>
> To use Quick Steps:
>
> https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Automate-common-or-repetitive-tasks-with-Quick-Steps-a9caf57e-0eb0-4b48-9141-a9904da0aaf9
>
> To use macros:
>
> http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/macro-move-folder/

Source [Making "Move to Folder" List Longer in Outlook 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d56451fc-f5d7-4a0d-abfa-0a3cbdfe6ab7/making-move-to-folder-list-longer-in-outlook-2013?forum=outlook)